# Compare Two Relationships withCount

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to count two different relationship items and then compare the two. My issue is that the counts are coming back wrong.

```
$server = Server::withCount('streams')->withCount('items')->has('streams', '!=', 'items')->orderBy('streams_count', 'desc')->first();
```

The `streams_count` is returning `0` and the `items_count` is returning `5`. However, `$server` is returning `null` but it should be grabbing the servers correctly judging by the data.

I have also attempted to do something with `having()`, but it is still grabbing servers where `items_count` and `streams_count` are equal.

```
$server = Server::withCount('streams')->withCount('items')->having('items_count', '!=', 'streams_count')->orderBy('streams_count', 'desc')->first();
```

Am I not doing the counts correctly?

What I am looking to do is basically, grab a server where the total counts of the streams associated and total counts of the items associated with servers, are not equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
->having('items_count', '!=', DB::raw('streams_count'))
```

Comment: Worked great. I knew I wasnt too far off.

Comment: @Jones, Can you please explain why Raw query in second  count?

Comment: @YasinPatel `->having('items_count', '!=', 'streams_count')` would compare the column with the *string* "streams_count". There is a `whereColumn()` method, but there is no `havingColumn()`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir you made my day :) Thanks